# How to use microsoft graph rest apis for one drive etc offline, without user login?

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

Need to use Microsoft graph API in the backend without login prompt, I was developing a web application which gets redirected to the login but can it done without login prompt with the access token

Comment: Do you like to use your web application as a background services or daemons that run on a server without the presence of a signed-in user..? have you referred this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)

Comment: Hi @Shreyoshi are you still looking for any help on this?